# Angluar2 Observable UI - Update Children in Object Array force Change?

Tags: angular, observable

Let's say I have a simple array object like so:

```
validationMessages = {
    'name': [{
        'type': 'required',
        'message': 'Name is required.',
        'enabled': 1
    },
    {
        'type': 'maxlength',
        'message': 'Name cannot be more than 50 characters long.',
        'enabled': 0
        }],
    'description': [
        {
            'type': 'required',
            'message': 'Description is required.',
            'enabled': 0
        },
    ]
};
```

I'm then displaying on load in my UI like so:

```
        <div *ngFor="let err of validationMessages.name">

            <div *ngIf="err.enabled == 1"  class="alert alert-danger">


                {{err.message}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Working fine.

However what I'd like to do is be able to update `validationMessages.name` array to update a given object to mark `enabled` 1 or 0. I'd want this then to update/re-run my UI.

I'm sure this can be done using observables, but what am I missing to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't modify the object within some event (button click, value change) or async call, you must tell Angular that you want the component to be refreshed.

```
controller(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
changeValidationMessages(): void {
   this.validationMessages...enabled = 0;
   this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}
```

There is no need to use Observables for that, but if you did, you would probably use the `async` pipe to display the messages. The pipe calls the `ChangeDetectorRef` itself.

The other way of making sure model changes get reflected in UI is using immutable objects (creating a new object copy whenever you want to modify an existing one), but it also adds some complexity.

Angular's change detection system is a topic worth knowing in more detail. You can check the following articles:

- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html
- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/27/three-things-you-didnt-know-about-the-async-pipe.html